# How to parallelise collections and prevent race condition

Tags: scala

I have List of users and I'm comparing each user to every other user by totaling their
values. This works fine but when I try to parallelise I get multiple race conditions as the variable totalVar is accessed by multiple threads at same time.

Can I have some pointers on how to parallelise the addition of the values for each list ?

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.JavaConverters._

object Question {

  case class User(id: String, value : BigInt) 

  var userList : java.util.List[User] = new java.util.ArrayList[User] 

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

      userList.add(new User("1" , 1))
      userList.add(new User("2" , 1))
      userList.add(new User("3" , 1))
      userList.add(new User("4" , 1))

      //Compare each user to every other user by totaling their
      //values
          var totalValue : BigInt = 0

      for(u <- userList.par){
        for(u1 <- userList.par){
           totalValue = totalValue + u1.value
           println("Adding "+u1.id+","+u1.value+ ","+totalValue)
        }
        println("Total is "+totalValue)
        totalValue = 0
      }

    }

}
```

Update :

I know this may seem like a pointless example but I'm facing a much more complicated problem and here I'm trying to ask the simplest question which will guide me in the direction of actual problem I am trying to resolve.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you do the same thing for each element of `userList`. This will just print the same stuff 4 times.

Comment: There is a chance that this will work in parallel if you simply put .par on the outer-most for loop. You probably have a quite limited number of cores anyway, so parallelizing on a single list should be enough. If you have a problem like this which runs in n^2, you can probably parallelize it to run in n.

Comment: @user470184 by the way, are you okay to count user with itself? Because your current code compares *every with every* not *every with everyone else*

Comment: I recently learned this mistake myself, you should never mutuate anything outside the scope of a par loop. (VARS) If you do, that item has to be atomic (ie. synchronized). Think about any VAR as like a single phone line: if everyone is calling it at once, some will just get a busy signal and fail. But a synchronized object is kind of like a queue, where java will make the next caller wait, and so on. Or the more scala way is to "yield" the whole loop which seems to be a lot safer it can be done! See answer by @om-nom-nom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you would not gain much by having two parallel collections (summing two integers is quite lightweight task and scheduling it over and over is not a good idea), it is easier to do with just one:

```
val total = 
  for(u <- userList.par) yield {
    var partialTotal = 0
    for(u1 <- userList){
      partialTotal += u1.value
      println("Adding "+u1.id+","+u1.value+ ","+totalValue)
    }
    partialTotal
  }.sum
```

Comment: if I was to removed the 'yield' keyword and not return 'partialTotal' would this affect parallelism ?

Comment: @user470184 it would affect correctness of you code: instead of List of partial counts of every user versus others you will get List of Unit values

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `AtomicInt` which is synchronized:

```
  val totalValue : new AtomicInt()

  for(u <- userList.par){
    for(u1 <- userList.par){
       totalValue.incrementAndGet(u1.value)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Isn't using *synchronized* word is kinda wrong, when we talk about *atomic* objects?